# LinkedIn profile field and Autobiographer badge

Tags: support

I decided to fill in my profile details so i could get the [autobiographer](/questions/tagged/autobiographer) badge. However, i got it before filling in the LinkedIn profile field.

Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I also suppose that there are people who don't have all of Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn and Google Profile accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LinkedIn field (along with the Facebook, Twitter and Google ones) is a new field and isn't counted for the Autobiographer badge.

Comment: What about now ? I have filed my profile but I haven't received the badge.